# Is it possible to bind the liistbox selected value to mediaelement source wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, mediaelement

The listbox contain images and the object assigned to the listbox have corresponding wmv file path. How to bind the selected path the the mediaelement through {binding}.

Geetha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ElementName to set the binding source to the list box, and then bind to a property of SelectedItem:

```
<ListBox Name="imageListBox" ... />
<MediaElement Source="{Binding ElementName=imageListBox, Path=SelectedItem.WmvPath}"/>
```